# WebConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I'm working on C# 2010. My website is unable to run due this error:

> The name 'WebConfigrationManager' does not exist in the current
>   context.

Although I've included `using System.Web.Configuration;`, the line of code the error points to is this:

```
String connectionString = WebConfigrationManager.ConnectionStrings["costr"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: _Where_ have you included the `using` directive?

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: yes I did .. I've added System.Configuration as a reference and it solved but it start to give an Exception error ...

Answer (score 7):

This already exist in system.web.dll, just add namespace
using System.Web.Configuration

Answer (score 5):

Am I the only one noticing that you misspelled WebConfigurationManager?

```
WebConfigrationManager
```

That might be one culprit.

Answer (score 4):

Add `System.Configuration` Reference and then the `using System.Configuration`

Answer (score 1):

You should a reference to System.Web

Answer (score 1):

I believe that that class resides in System.Web. At least in .Net 2.0 it does.

Add an reference to that an try again.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the namespace:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 string cnStr=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["costr"].ConnectionString;
```

Or

```
string cnStr=System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
```